# How to build a layout of single line and multi line labels in iOS autolayout?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have an application in swift,and have encountered an autolayout issue. I've come up with the solution to it, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

So, here's the issue:
I have **two labels** in a table view cell. *The first one* should only have one line, and *the second one* must have as many lines as needed and take up as much vertical space as needed. *The first label* should always be shown fully and, therefore, determine the position, the size, and the number of lines of *the second label*. Texts for both are set programmatically when drawing the cell, of course.

The solution seems to be pretty simple: *Anchor the first label to the left, center it vertically, anchor the second label to the parent top, right, bottom and the right side of the first one. Set the number of lines to 0 for the second label.* The editor shows no warnings or errors.

This is how it looks like:

[image: Constraints]

In most cases it looks good, like on the picture below, but sometimes not (**red arrows at the picture below**):

[image: Screenshots]

The first label should have absolute priority and never be truncated, wrapped, or cut, but this happens. What am I doing wrong?

UPD: For the question to be more clear, the first label is so called 'margin label', it represents the margin and the indicator of the cell. This is done to imitate a tree structure. The second is, of course, the text itself. '>' is for the closed comment, 'v' is for the opened.

Comment: check background color of label

Comment: nope, doesn't help..

Comment: If your first label holds static content then fix its width to minimum as required

Comment: No, the problem is that _both_ labels have dynamic content, as you see the first label can have different widths in different cells.

Comment: firstly tell how are representing " > " and " v "?

Comment: Ok, I have added an update to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the first label (the `>`) and go into the measurements panel in Interface Builder.

Near the bottom it will have a value for "Content Compression Resistance". Currently it will be `251` or `751` (I can't remember which) and it will be equal to the other label.

Change this value to `1000`. This will stop it from compressing and make the second label compress instead.

Comment: Didn't work, too.. Im starting to think that maybe the issue is table view somehow rendering it wrong

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Just realized I was setting it in another place. That solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

set height constraint for first label and set 1 for 'lines' attribute

Answer (score 0):

you can set the trailing of the first label is >= to the leading of the second label

Comment: Nope, didn't work and besides the edtor started to show warnings here

Answer (score 0):

Increase the content compression resistance priority of the first label. If needed increase the horizontal content hugging priority of the second label.